# Unable to change Stock configuration

Tags: event-observer, configuration, magento-1, stock, quantity

Strange issue here...

This project has been live for some years, there are about 40k skus, and around 15k of sales & customers. I must say stock management has been used sometimes, but this project has never used stock **quantity** until now, they have only used stock status feature

I am trying to enable `cataloginventory_options_can_subtract` (that's the first option, in **Catalog Inventory** config section), but it seems that web request never ends, even in our local environment (with no timeout limits) it loads eternally

Enabling or disabling the different indexes does not make any change

So, question is: which code, or event, is fired while saving this config change? So I can give a look, and try to patch this, via shell script, or something

I'd try to change the parameter directly in `core_config_data` database table, and then reindex or something like that... but I'd take a look better to the code I am asking for, to be sure this won't affect in some way the integrity of the store... Any tips?

Comment: Did you find the solution Raul? I've the exact issue but I'm unable to fix it. This is the only post that I've found about this issue. Can you help me to the right direction regarding this issue?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138984)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, which event is fired while saving this config change:

There are **two events directly dispatched during this process**:

The first one is `admin_system_config_changed_section_cataloginventory` and is dispatched in the `saveAction` of the `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/ConfigController.php` right after the config is being saved to the database.

The `app/core/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml` declares an observer on this specific event:

```
<admin_system_config_changed_section_cataloginventory>
    <observers>
        <inventory>
            <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
            <method>updateItemsStockUponConfigChange</method>
        </inventory>
    </observers>
</admin_system_config_changed_section_cataloginventory>
```

Where the observer function looks like this:

```
public function updateItemsStockUponConfigChange($observer)
{
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->updateSetOutOfStock();
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->updateSetInStock();
    Mage::getResourceSingleton('cataloginventory/stock')->updateLowStockDate();
    return $this;
}
```

On the other hand, under the `app/code/core/Mage/Index/etc/config.xml` you will find the following code:

```
<core_config_data_save_commit_after>
    <observers>
        <index>
            <class>index/observer</class>
            <method>processConfigDataSave</method>
        </index>
    </observers>
</core_config_data_save_commit_after>
```

This `core_config_data_save_commit_after` event is being dispatched under  the `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php` in the `afterCommitCallback` function. (**Note that this event is dispatched for every system config section save, not only for the cataloginventory section**).

Its name tells it all, it is dispatched after the commit, you can find the details in the `save` function:

```
$this->_beforeSave();
if ($this->_dataSaveAllowed) {
    $this->_getResource()->save($this);
    $this->_afterSave();
}
$this->_getResource()->addCommitCallback(array($this, 'afterCommitCallback'))
    ->commit();
```

The observer function linked to that event looks like this:

```
public function processConfigDataSave(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $configData = $observer->getEvent()->getConfigData();
    $this->_indexer->processEntityAction(
        $configData,
        Mage_Core_Model_Config_Data::ENTITY,
        Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_SAVE
    );
}
```

So to me, those two observers are the suspect you should investigate.

*More information about them:*

- The `CatalogInventory` observer function calls 3 different functions, each of them is making updates to the `stock_item` database table, which could be a huge resource consumer as you're dealing with a huge database.
- The `Index` observer function on the other hand processes the index related to the config section saved. And there is definitely an index related to the cataloginventory stock.

*Going further:*

It's good to note that the `processEntityAction` method of the `app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php` (called by the Index observer function) also dispatched two events:

- `start_process_event` (followed by the event type name)
- `end_process_event` (followed by the event type name)

Even if the first one is not used, the second one is being observer by `app/code/core/Mage/CatalogInventory/etc/config.xml`:

```
<end_process_event_cataloginventory_stock_item_save>
    <observers>
        <cataloginventory>
            <class>cataloginventory/observer</class>
            <method>reindexProductsMassAction</method>
        </cataloginventory>
    </observers>
</end_process_event_cataloginventory_stock_item_save>
```

Where the observer function is a reindex:

```
public function reindexProductsMassAction($observer)
{
    Mage::getSingleton('index/indexer')->indexEvents(
        Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, Mage_Index_Model_Event::TYPE_MASS_ACTION
    );
}
```

This is a good example of the differences between **what events are being dispatched during a process explicitely** and **what events are being dispatched during a process implicitely**.

Comment: Excellent! This is exactly what I was requiring, no need to wait for more answers. Points for you